# Creating Sublists from a "List"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list in a file,
looks like this

```
c4a24534,2434b375,e750c718, ....
```

I have split at "," and brought the below list.

```
x=
['c4a2', '4534'] 
['2434', 'b375']
['e750', 'c718']
```

I need to make two new lists out of this

```
i=
'c4a2'
'2434'
'e750'
```

and

```
 q=
'4534'
'b375'
'c718'
```

I have tried :

```
for x in line:
    x = [i.split() for i in x]
```

With this I am splitting the x .This gives me "i" part but how do i get the rest "q" ?

Comment: it's a file where each line have a list with only 2 elements ?

Comment: yes and i need to seperately process those two elements

Comment: and the results must be a string or a list ? (a and b)

Comment: Thats right..so i have ['19df', 'cf47'] and i need a=19df and b=cf47... similarly for the rest of the data in the file

Comment: What do you mean "I have a list in a file"? Please either show the file or the list you have. What you show is invalid syntax, but also doesn't look like a file sample.

Comment: ok. I have now shown the file contents.. its a text file.

Comment: @user3615736 is it just a one line of comma-separated values? See my answer, is it what you are expecting the code to do?

Comment: Please... if we have answered your question , approve our message. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have read a list of lists, use `zip()` to turn columns into rows:

```
file_result = [
    ['19df', 'b35d']
    ['fafa', 'bbaf']
    ['dce9', 'cf47']
]

a, b = zip(*file_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking for granted that you've already parsed the file:

```
x = [['c4a2', '4534'], ['2434', 'b375'], ['e750', 'c718']]
i = [a[0] for a in x] # ['c4a2', '2434', 'e750']
q = [a[1] for a in x] # ['4534', 'b375', 'c718']
```

This takes the first and second element of each sub-list, and puts it into a new variable.

Comment: i = [a[0] for a in x]  is picking the "c" from "c4a2" and "4" from "4534"

Comment: @user3615736 it's not... do you somehow have `[a[0][0] for a in x]` ?

Comment: I guess `x = ['c4a2', '4534']`, which does not match the structure of `x` in my example.

Comment: ok.. i have added in my question, how exactly my file looks like

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a contents of `input.txt` file:

```
c4a24534,2434b375,e750c718
```

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for splitting into two lists:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    i, q = zip(*((x[:4], x[4:]) for line in f for x in line.split(',')))

print i
print q
```

Prints:

```
('c4a2', '2434', 'e750')
('4534', 'b375', 'c718')
```

These are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), if you need to make lists from them, call `list()` on each:

```
print list(i)
print list(q)
```

Comment: tried, its assigning all the numbers to "i" and \n to "q" .. seems missing it marginally

Comment: @user3615736 clarify the format then. Show more lines and what `i` and `q` should be equal to.

Comment: tried split('\n') instead of (',') and i get 'c4a2', '', '2434', '', 'e750',  for "i" . The numbers are right. How do i get rid of the '' that i get between them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ast
file = open("file.txt","r")

i = list()
q = list()

for line in file:
    testarray = ast.literal_eval(line)
    q.append(testarray.pop())
    i.append(testarray.pop())

print(i)
print(q)
```

something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to separate the list into two collections.

```
x=[
['c4a2', '4534'], 
['2434', 'b375'],
['e750', 'c718']
]

i,q = zip(*x)

print i
print q
```

Result:

```
('c4a2', '2434', 'e750')
('4534', 'b375', 'c718')
```

These are tuples, though. If you really want lists, you would need to convert them.

```
i,q = map(list, zip(*x))
#or:
i,q = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*x)]
#or:
i,q = zip(*x)
i, q = list(i), list(q)
```